# Building my JS library, a couple questions

Tags: javascript, oop, frameworks, local-storage

I'm building a library (https://github.com/OscarGodson/storageLocker), a localStorage wrapper to be more exact, but because this is my first try at OO JavaScript I'm still learning and I have a couple questions.

1. I've seen in other libraries that sometimes they wrap them in a anonymous function. Do I, or should I, do that with this? And if so, how without breaking anything?
2. For the internal API (basically, the internal functions) how should I write them? Should add them to the main object e.g. `storageLocker.prototype.myInternalFunction()` or just `myInternalFunction()` randomly in my script? I didn't want the functions to be global though... One of the functions for example just checks a bunch of items in the JSON, sees if their objects, and then checks what the object type is (like `Date()`) and then converts it.
3. How/where should I add global, to my script, vars? e.g. i have a var called `patterns` that is something like `var patterns = {"date":/\/Date\(([0-9]+)\)\//}` how should I add that into my script?

Thanks a lot. I want to write my script the *right way* so im asking you guys. I don't know of any JS guys locally that do any OO JS, they're all old school types...

Comment: I highly recommend reading about (JavaScript) closures. They are what gives this language its power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://nefariousdesigns.co.uk/archive/2010/10/object-oriented-javascript-follow-up-part-2-technical/

has a decent section on namespacing worth reading.

> http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

is also another good overview.

For more great material on good javascript practices, check out

> http://javascript.crockford.com/

After our discussion in the comments, I've changed the example to this:

```
var storageLocker = function (selector) {

    var _selector = selector || "default value";

    function myPrivateFunction() {

    }

    var public = {

        get: function () {
            return _selector;
        },

        uppercase : function () {
            _selector = _selector.toUpperCase()
            return this;
        }

    }
    return public;

};

// use:
var test = storageLocker("search for this").uppercase().get();;

alert(test);
```

While this isn't exactly an example of a library/module (because you're accessing the code by calling the constructor directly), it is an example of keeping the same object in scope for further chaining of methods.  Actually it's not returning the `storageLocker` object, it's returning the 'public' object, but that object has access to the `storageLocker`'s scope through closure.

There could be other better ways to do this by perhaps returning the `storageLocker` object itself, but that would require a bit more thinking through.

Comment: yes, there is a missing }; I'll correct that.  Selecting items is just an implementation detail for your public methods, isn't it?

Comment: in order to 'chain' methods together like jQuery does, each public method needs to return the module/object itself, so further function calls can be made.  I'll update the example...

Comment: Well, i was getting an error shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300135/set-my-var-to-an-anonymous-function-with-a-parameter

Comment: oh hey, also, in your public var, should those `function myFunctionName(){}` be in JSON like format like the poster above? Im getting errors, so thats why im asking...

Comment: yes, you're right, it should be json format - that's what I get for posting untested code. Was just trying to send you in the right direction. I'll revise.

Comment: It's fine... :D thanks a lot, but im still (when doing `()` at the end) getting that error in that link i sent. I modified my code to be in JSON format too and added a return public at the end... any idea on how to fix that? I think after that is fixed ill be good.

Comment: I edited the example, and actually tested it this time and it worked.  In this pattern, you do need the (); at the end of the definition, to actually execute the code and return the public object to the myLib variable.

Comment: So how do I select localStorage objects like: `storageLocker('someStorageObject').get()`? i can't figure that part out. My code looks identical to yours now, but im still getting that error in the link above... sorry

Comment: it looks like you're calling storageLocker directly.  I think you need to be accessing the methods from the variable which holds your module. in my example that's the myLib variable.  So you would call it like so: myLib.storageLocker('someStorageObject').get(). storageLocker would return 'this', while get() would return the thing you're retrieving (and would not be 'chainable' after that).  Hope that's on the right track...

Comment: FYI, for all the help i marked yours as correct already, but if you could show me how to do the `storageLocker('selectedItemToChain').save({'someitem':'to save to selectedItemToChain'})` thatd be awesome... ive been working on this all day to get it from a normal script to OO JS and make it all best practice like and this is the last thing i can't figure out

Comment: the comparisons in jQuery are: $ = the myLib variable; .find() returns a $ object (not the thing it finds), so is chainable, and .text() returns a string, so is not chainable.

Comment: Well, so, for example, jQuery scopes $ and jQuery so you do `jQuery('div').someAPICall()`, and i wanted to match that sort of functionality as it's personally the most intuitive. My thought behind it is `storageLocker(param)` where param IS the storageLocker object you want to select which in reality is just the localStorage item you want to select. It makes sense and was how it was working before, but i cant match it anymore like this :(

Comment: ...anyways, just, i wanted `storageLocker()` to be  == to `jQuery()`. Im not sure how to do it...

Comment: I see - the design for that is more complex, and is beyond the idea of just having a library with public and private methods.  You will have to pay attention to what the constructor storageLocker('selector') is returning.  Sorry I couldn't be more helpful :)

Comment: I played with the example a little bit more and I think it is closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: Man, thanks so much! This should point me in the right direction, if not completely. It looks perfect. You rock :D Do you have a blog or twitter account?

Comment: And FYI: seems to be working great :D. Just saved my first item with storageLocker.save({'test':'test'});

Comment: awesome! :)  I have a lame blog www.allannienhuis.com, but never have time to do anything worthwhile on there. :)

Comment: Great, just wanted to give you a shout out! My script is picking up some traction and I'm trying to keep track of who helped me get the script up to par. So, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I'd say:

1) the purpose of this technique is not pollute the global namespace. That is a good thing.
   In the example below you can see that all your interaction with the library is via one object MyLibrary. Public API is the return value of the anonymous function.

```
var MyLibrary = function() {
// private
   this.InternalVariable = 'some value';

   function internalFunction(x,y) {
      return x + y;
      }

     function getInternalVariable() {
    return this.InternalVariable;
}
// public
   return {
      publicVariable : '1.0',
      publicFunction : function(x,y) {
         return x + y
         },
 accessInternalVariable : function() {

     return getInternalVariable();
     }
      }
   }();
```

2) see also the example above on how to place your "internal" functions

3) if you global variable is some kind of a configuration option, I'd just make public setter/getter and kept the variable "private"

Comment: Awesome! You rock man. And no, there are no configuration options, so you `this.InternalVariable` should work fine. I'll try it out and if all this works fine ill mark as correct ;) thanks again!

Comment: modifying my script right now, but while im doing this... will chaining still work? I purposely wrote my script so that it'd chain, and just want to make sure that doing it like this would work...

Comment: For chaining the methods have to return the object of which they are member.

Comment: Sorry... i don't understand :( right now for example doing: `storageLocker('date-test').get('someItem')` returns `[object Object]` in my console? I basically just put what you have (minus the `()` at the end) and then all my functions in the return as you have them. Any ideas?

Comment: `this.InternalVariable` is precisely **not** what you want - it will put `InternalVariable` as a global variable! (Outside an object, `this` is `window` for `function(){}()`, you'd need `new function(){}()` to make it another object, but that's not a good idea)  Use `var InternalVariable` instead.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: That is not correct. Notice that the anonymous function is executed immediately and returns an object. this.InternalVariable is accessible only through the object returned from the anonymous function. I updated the example to show how to access the fucntion

Comment: @jira: you're wrong; try running precisely that snippet in Firebug and then look at `InternalVariable`. Inside `new function(){}()`, `this` would be a new object, but in `function(){}()` it's the parent scope's `this` which will in this case be `window`.