# Set my var to an anonymous function with a parameter?

Tags: javascript, oop, local-storage

I'm building my first OO JS library and im having a little trouble with one piece that's probably super easy...

I have this:

```
var storageLocker = function(catalog){
    if(catalog){
        this.catalog = catalog;
    }
    //my code...
}()
```

i need to be able to do what other libraries like jQuery do where you can select an element (in my case select a localStorage item) and then chain other functions to it. I had all that working, but for best practice and to make it more extensible later i put it in a anonymous function and now i can't figure out how to have the syntax of:

```
storageLocker('localStorageItem').save({"item":"an example item saved to localStorageItem"})
```

but right now if i do that now with that syntax it returns this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'storageLocker' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I read your other question about this, and if you want to use private variables, you need to work with closure. That is, you should use this construct _with_ `()` at the end, but you need to return a second function from the inside, that handles your actual logic. There was a good example at the other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `()` at the end of the function body.

You wrote `var storageLocker = function(...) { ... }()`, which creates an anonymous function, **calls it**, and assigns *the result* to `storageLocker`.

It's equivalent to

```
function anonymous(...) { ... };
var storageLocker = anonymous();
```

Since the function doesn't return anything, `storageLocker` ends up being `undefined`, and is not a function.

Comment: Been trying, but i had to wait 10 mins :)